# Graphs where any cycles are adjacent

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Graphs with minimum degree three that any two cycles have common vertex, have been characterized by Lovász.  I see this result from the Plumer article （On the cyclic connectivity of planar graphs (1972). ), and the original article of Lovász doesn't appear to be in English.

**THEOREM 1.** (Lovász) If $G$ has no two point-disjoint cycles and the degree of every point in $G$ is at least 3, then $G$ belongs to one of the following three families of graphs:

I. $V(G)=\left\{a, b, c, d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_k\right\}, k \geq 1$. Each $d_i$ is joined to each of $a, b$, and $c$ and in addition any number of the lines $ab, bc, ca$ may be present (subject of course to the restriction that each point of $G$ have degree $\geq 3)$.

II. $G$ is a "wheel", i.e., $G$ consists of a cycle $C$ and one other point $u$ not on $c$, but joined to each point of $C$.

III. $G=K_5$, the complete graph on 5 points.

Let $G$ be a graph. for subgraphs $H_1$,$H_2$ are said to be *adjacent* if there exists $u\in H_1$ and $v\in H_2$ such that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent in $G$. That it, $C_1$ and $C_2$ share a vertex or have at least one edge joining them.

Today, **our graph class extends a bit:**  **any two cycles are adjacent. Did some people characterize the graph class?**

NaturalLogZ in [cyclic connectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859349/the-relationship-between-cyclic-connectivity-and-vertex-disjoint-cycles/4859495#4859495)  found that for the vertex version of cyclic connectivity, so I think this characterization is import.

**Observation** $cκ(G)=∞$ if and only if $G$ contains no two non-adjacent  cycles

Comment: There is a polynomial time algorithm to check whether a graph contains no two non-adjacent cycles (and more generally no k non-adjacent cycles). This follows from the fact that these graphs have a polynomial number of induced paths, and they can all be enumerated in polynomial time. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2023.10.003

Comment: @LouisEsperet Thank you.  I will read it first.